# Docker Compose networking: hostnames in nginx not resolving

Tags: networking, nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, docker-compose

I've attempted to migrate my stack to use version 2 docker-compose.yml and have run into a problem with network hostnames not being resolved by nginx.

My stack involves an nginx reverse proxy (on debian:wheezy) that serves secure content via several other software components of which I won't go into detail (see config below).

In the version 1 yaml, I used environment variables from docker links alongside with LUA script to insert them into the nginx.conf (using nginx-extras). This worked perfectly as a reverse proxy in front of the docker containers.

In the version 2 yaml I am using the hostnames as generated by docker networking. I am able to successfully ping these hostnames from within the container, however nginx is unable to resolve them.

```
2016/05/04 01:23:44 [error] 5#0: *3 no resolver defined to resolve ui, client: 10.0.2.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

Here is my current config:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  # back-end
  api:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - worker
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/mmaps
      - /var/log/mmaps/api:/mmaps/log
    volumes_from:
      - apidata
    command: sh -c 'rm -rf /mmaps/tmp/pids/server.pid; rails server thin -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000'

  # background process workers
  worker:
    build: .
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
      QUEUE: "*"
      TERM_CHILD: "1"
    volumes:
      - ./:/mmaps
      - /var/log/mmaps/worker:/mmaps/log
    volumes_from:
      - apidata
    command: rake resque:work

  # front-end
  ui:
    image: magiandev/mmaps-ui:develop
    depends_on:
      - api
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/log/mmaps/ui:/var/log/nginx

  # database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pewpewpew
    volumes_from: 
      - mysqldata
    volumes:
      - /var/log/mmaps/db:/var/log/mysql

  # key store
  redis:
    image: redis:2.8.13
    user: root
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly yes"]
    volumes_from:
      - redisdata
    volumes:
      - /var/log/mmaps/redis:/var/log/redis

  # websocket server
  monitor:
    image: magiandev/mmaps-monitor:develop
    depends_on:
      - api
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"

  # media server
  media:
    image: nginx:1.7.1
    volumes_from: 
      - apidata
    ports:
      - "3080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/media/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - /srv/mmaps/public:/usr/local/nginx/html:ro
      - /var/log/mmaps/mediapool:/usr/local/nginx/logs

  # reverse proxy
  proxy:
    build: docker/proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes: 
      - /var/log/mmaps/proxy:/var/log/nginx


  apidata:
    image: busybox:ubuntu-14.04
    volumes:
      - /srv/mmaps/public:/mmaps/public
    command: echo api data

  mysqldata:
    image: busybox:ubuntu-14.04
    volumes:
      - /srv/mmaps/db:/var/lib/mysql
    command: echo mysql data

  redisdata:
    image: busybox:ubuntu-14.04
    volumes:
      - /srv/mmaps/redis:/data
    command: echo redis data

  # master data
  # convenience container for backups
  data:
    image: busybox:ubuntu-14.04
    volumes_from:
      - apidata
      - mysqldata
      - redisdata
    command: echo mmaps data
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  # permanent redirect to https
  server {
    listen         80;
    rewrite        ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
  }

  server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://ui:80$request_uri;
    }

    location /monitor/ {
      proxy_pass http://monitor:8888$request_uri;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /api/ {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      proxy_pass http://api:3000$request_uri;
    }

    location /files/ {
      client_max_body_size 0;
      proxy_pass http://media:80$request_uri;
    }

    location /mediapool/ {
      proxy_pass http://media:80$request_uri;
      add_header  X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;
      if ($request_uri ~ "^.*\/(.*\..*)\?download=true.*$"){
          set $fname $1;
          add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$fname"';
      }
      proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
      root   /var/www;
    }
  }
}

# stay in the foreground so Docker has a process to track
daemon off;
```

After some reading I have tried to use 'dnsmasq' and set `resolver 127.0.0.1` within the nginx.conf but I cannot get this to work:

```
2016/05/04 01:54:26 [error] 6#0: recv() failed (111: Connection refused) while resolving, resolver: 127.0.0.1:53
```

Is there a better way to configure nginx to proxy pass to my containers that works with V2?

Answer (score -1):

You can rename your containers and resolving by names.

Comment: I haven't returned to this problem since. My nginx conf is already using the container host names. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @MeiramChuzhenbayev IPs are assigned dynamically, and can change over time, how would you write them in /etc/hosts ?